# Tomcat server error on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Can anyone help me to solve the following case?

I am trying to generate my first web site using java and working with Eclipse Galileo running on Ubuntu 9.10. Since I generate my first lines of code I haven't seen the web. All the time when I try to run the program I get the following error:

> Several ports (8080, 8080) required by Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have another Tomcat instance running and using the same port. Try this command in the terminal .

```
kill $(ps -aef | grep java | grep apache-tomcat-7.0.27 | awk '{print $2}')
```

Then try to restart the Tomcat again.

Alternatively, You can try to `/bin` subfolder of the Tomcat installation folder and execute the `shutdown.sh` (Unix) script. If in vain, close Eclipse and then open the [System manager](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1932527) and kill all java and/or javaw processes.

Ref : [Same problem with perfect solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064733/several-ports-8005-8080-8009-required-by-tomcat-server-at-localhost-are-alre). Next time when you encounter such errors, just copy and paste the error in Google. There are similar/identical problems solved. You get the idea. =]

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting tomcat from within eclipse, you can change the port tomcat runs on from 8080, to say 8070 or 8090 by editing the server.xml file.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```